# Opening new activity by pressing searchview without focus and pop up keyboard when return the previous activity

Tags: java, android, searchview

I spent many days but can't overcome a challenge in which I want to open an search activity after pressing searchview icon from main activity but don't gain focus and pop up keyboard by doing back pressing to return the main activity.
Both main activity and search activity contains toolbars and search menus. In detail, the code for them are as following:

menu of main activity

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<item android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_search"
    android:title="Search"
    android:iconifiedByDefault="false"
    app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"/>
    <!--app:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"-->

<item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:title="Thu nghiem"/>
```

menu of search activity

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<item android:id="@+id/search_action_search"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_search"
    android:title="Search"
    app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"/>

<item android:id="@+id/search_action_settings"
    android:title="Detail"/>
```

In main activity, I tried

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.example_menu, menu);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).getActionView();
    searchView.setIconified(true);
    searchView.setFocusable(false);
    searchView.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
    searchView.clearFocus();
    return true;

}
```

Also, I tried some different ways but can't achieve successfully.

Comment: I decide to end up this question because I have found the solution by myself. The solution's code is as followings:
`public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.example_menu, menu);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).getActionView();
searchView.setOnSearchClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
}
});
return true;
}`

Answer (score 0):

use this line to prevent the keyboard from appearing in your activity.

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN);
```

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately, this approach doesn't work. I think the reason is that I use android.support.v7.widget.SearchView rather than android.widget.SearchView. However, I have solved it after many experiments for a week. See the solution on above.